# How to specify groupid, artifact and version directly in dependencies section of BUILD file using Bazel?

Tags: bazel

How to specify groupid, artifact and version directly in dependencies section of BUILD file using Bazel?

I am trying to convert a simple gradle project to bazel project. Can't really use `generate_workspace` since I have a gradle project (not maven).

I am wondering if there is just a easier way to specify GAV in the dependencies itself in the BUILD file so it would look something like this

```
java_binary(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**"]),
    deps = ["com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8"],
    main_class = "com.hello.sample.Foo"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `maven_jar()` directly?

In WORKSPACE:

```py
maven_jar(
    name = "com_google_guava_guava",
    artifact = "com.google.guava:guava:18.0",
    sha1 = "cce0823396aa693798f8882e64213b1772032b09",
)
```

In BUILD:

```py
java_binary(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**"]),
    deps = ["@com_google_guava_guava//jar"],
    main_class = "com.hello.sample.Foo"
)
```

See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#maven_jar

Comment: do I have to use `maven_jar()` function for each of my dependency? is there a `maven_jars()` function that takes an array?

Comment: Yes, you do, and there isn't a maven_jars() function, although you can write such a function yourself as a macro using Skylark in a .bzl file. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html

Comment: There's also https://github.com/johnynek/bazel-deps, which might be useful.